# Php logic whether to use if else conditionals or polymorphism

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Guys what I m trying to implement here is I have suppose 5 buttons (with different options,which are displayed one after the another using jquery and data is sent using ajax).

```
<div id="div1">
<button value="1" class="div1button">1</button>
<button value="2" class="div1button">2</button>
<button value="3" class="div1button">3</button>
<button value="4" class="div1button">4</button>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<button value="a" class="div2button">a</button>
<button value="b" class="div2button">b</button>
<button value="c" class="div2button">c</button>
<button value="d" class="div2button">d</button>
</div>
```

Now the div 2 is hidden when the user clicks any one of the button on div1 ... div2 is displayed, the value of the button clicked is passed using jquery and sql query is executed using ajax.. 
Now the php which execute the query contains

```
$_GET['valDiv1']
$_GET['valDiv2']
```

The php checks where val1 is defined or not and the vice versa after val of div 2 is obtained ... the problem is here....

I have around 5 divs the now I need to check the values of all div exist or only 1 or 2 .. etc .... HOW to solve this?
To check this I have to implement to many if else 
LIKE :: 
if div1 is defined ... do this 
if div1 and div2 is defined ...do that
if div1 and div2 and div3 is defined ... do something
if div2 and div3 and div5 is defined

So this is where I'm stuck.

I'm a beginner please help, is there a better way to achieve what I want?

## Solved

Thanks to @Igor

```
$selected = array('val1' => null, 'val2' => null, ...);
$selected['val1'] = $_GET['valDiv1'];
$selected['val2'] = $_GET['valDiv2'];
foreach($elements as $val => $key) {
    if($val == 'val1' && $key == 'any') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM details";
    } else {
    if($key != null) {  
            if($key != 'any') {
                if($i>0) {
                $sql .= " AND $val='$key'";
                } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE $val='$key'";
                $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what you needed to do instead of div1 div2 button1 button2. You can simplify everything if the difference in effects are small, but if each button has a very specific outcome then you will have to use a case or a lot of nested if statements.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by polymorphism here. Is this a simple case of pre-requisites where one of the valid values for part 1 must be populated before part 2 can be accepted? If so, you might have to do a query with each step like `SELECT id FROM valid_values WHERE name IN (...)` where that last part is the list of values.

Comment: @Chris ok Thanks would there be a problem if I use alot of nested if else I mean around 15-20?

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your answer! it will be of much help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are lots of approaches to optimize it. One of them could be to store all the choices not in separate variables, but in an array, e.g.:

```
$selected = array('val1' => null, 'val2' => null, ...);
$selected['val1'] = $_GET['valDiv1'];
$selected['val2'] = $_GET['valDiv2'];
...
```

And when checking you could do

```
if (array_search(null, $selected) === false) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been thinking about! One more question what if I used too many nested if else would there be a problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer . That was really helpful!